# aws ECS (with ec2), running docker-compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

Say you want to run

- a webserver (which can be nginx + uwsgi)
- filebeat to collect logs (it basically watches logfiles of nginx and send the log contents to another host specified in the configuration)

I can run the two services with docker-compose.

Question is how can I run the two services on `ec2-based ECS`

ECS task seems to be associated with a docker image.
And separate task (web task / filebeat task) seems to be run on separate EC2.

They need to run on the same ec2 host (because filebeat needs to collect logs outputted by webserver)

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can put multiple containers in one task.

Comment: how? one task has only 1 docker image. @Marcin

Comment: In your task definition your provide a [list of container defnition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definitions). Thus one task definition can contain multiple docker images. What's more you can define shared volumes between them, and so on.